# What can you do with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, language-features

Everything I know about AppleScript I taught myself and was wondering if I missed any cool features. I know you can make the computer talk to and control applications but is there anything else it can do or is it time to move on to a new language?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific in your question, or maybe list some of the things you wish to accomplish. Applescript is very robust; controlling scriptable applications is a very deep subject unto itself.

Comment: you don't have to go into detail just cool things that can be done with applescript. I can always look up how or ask another question if I don't understand.

Comment: @mtwisterr: "language features" refers to language functionality and aspects of the language itself (e.g. static typing, weak typing, dynamic scoping, native types, supported programming paradigms, extensibility (which is actually a category of features),  built-in functions and operators, standard libraries, variadic functions (functions with a variable number of arguments), control flow features (another category, including things like loops, exceptions, continuations), ...), rather than applications of the language. It seems like you're asking for the latter.

Comment: Perhaps this should be renamed to, "Why cool things have you guys done with AppleScript?", or something of that nature.

Comment: @Rev316: That is still really subjective. The things that I think are cool (like automating marketing pieces with XML in InDesign with Applescript) would probably be a real snoozer of a subject for others. Again, Applescript is really just about controlling other applications as the other answers have shown; the language itself is really quite dull, IMHO.

Comment: @Philip You make a valid point. But the OP suggested to me what *neat* applescripts have you used, not so much the capabilities of the language itself? Would it still be dull, probably. :)

Answer (score 8):

The coolest thing about Applescript I've recently discovered, is that you can script almost anything on your mac. So even application, which don't support Applescript natively, can be used in a workflow.
This is possible, because you can just "press" buttons as if you're sitting on the computer.

```
tell application "GhostReader" to activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using command down
```

I used this to copy and paste a website from Safari and have it read by GhostReader, a proprietary text to speech tool.

Comment: It's a text to speech tool. In the example above, I used it to read a webpage aloud.

http://www.convenienceware.com/ghostreader.php

Comment: hendrik, can you share some of your AppleScript? I've been looking for a way to do exactly what you're describing.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to Applescript, application control is where the action is. There's not much of a  "wow" factor within Applescript itself unless you're a real language nerd. It's really more about presenting a set of easy-to-use tools to control the "wow" factor of *other* applications.

I've seen (and have) examples of Applescript playing simple card games and other text-based fun (well...as much fun as one can have viewing one `display dialog` after another), but these are (at best) academic exercises to show off the robustness of the language itself or a specific feature of Applescript.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, but I use this all the time!

```
tell application "System Events" 
display dialog "$msg" with icon stop buttons {"Foo", "Bar", "OK"} default button "OK" 
end tell
```

Whenever I'm doing some shell programming, it's convenient for my operation to bring awareness into Finder, via a dialog.

Very handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate everything on your Mac, this is a great time saver.
I remember coding shell on C++ on Windows, it's just a pain to automate Windows.